# Cerberus and validating a list containing dicts

Tags: python, cerberus

I'm trying to validatie the following doc.

```
document = {
            'days': {
                'Monday': [{
                    'address': 'my address',
                    'city': 'my town'
                }],
                'Tuesday': [{
                    'address': 'my address',
                    'city': 'my town'
                }]
            }
        }
```

Using the following schema.

```
    schema = {
                'days': {
                    'type': 'dict',
                    'allowed': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
                    'schema': {
                        'type': 'list',
                        'schema': {
                            'address': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'city': {
                                'type': 'string', 'required': True
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
v = Validator(schema)
if not v.validate(document, schema):
  raise Exception("Configuration file is not valid", v.errors)
```

I get the following error: {days: ['must be of dict type']}

I cannot figure out how to validate the dict that is contained within the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.  You can use `valuesrules` to say "whatever the keys are, here's the rules for the values".  Then, in the list, you need a schema that says the list has dicts, then a schema inside that for the elements.  There may be a simpler way to do it, but this passes your document.

```
schema = {
            'days': {
                'type': 'dict',
                'allowed': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
                'valuesrules': {
                    'type': 'list',
                    'schema': {
                        'type': 'dict',
                        'schema': {
                            'address': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'city': {
                                'type': 'string', 'required': True
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```